# Behaviour of listable vector functions

Tags: functions, function-construction

The behavior of Listable vector functions is weird, the output of the code below for me was {{2, 6, 12}, {1, 8, 27}} and {f[1, 1, 1], f[2, 2, 2], f[3, 3, 3]}. From the second output I would expect a list with 3 sub lists for the first, but you don't get that. Is it supposed to work like that or is it a bug? (I know that taking the transpose of output 1 I get the output 2 format, but I have functions with higher rank tensors, which makes it hard to keep track of these transposes)

````
f =Function[{x,y,z}, {x*y+z, z^2*x}  ];
SetAttributes[f,Listable]
f[ {1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}]
Clear@f;
SetAttributes[f,Listable];
f[ {1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}]```
````

Comment: Use `Function[..., Listable]` instead, as the listabile attribute is not getting invoked. The head is evaluated before that listability attribute is applied, and once the head gets replaced with the Function object, the listability of `f` is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The `Listable` has no effect when you use `f` this way. `f` gets immediately replaced with the `Function` expression (heads are evaluated before arguments), and `Function` is not `Listable`. And arithmetic functions are designed to work with lists (and are `Listable`). So consider,

```
in1 = {a, b, c};
in2 = {m, n, o};
in3 = {x, y, z};
{in1*in2 + in3, in3^2*in1}

(* {{a*m + x, b*n + y, c*o + z}, {a*x^2, b*y^2, c*z^2}} *)
```

This is the same as you get from the `Function` you assigned to `f`.

Contrast that with these:

```
SetAttributes[g, Listable];
g[x_, y_, z_] := {x*y + z, z^2*x};
g[in1, in2, in3]

(* {{a*m + x, a*x^2}, {b*n + y, b*y^2}, {c*o + z, c*z^2}} *)

h = Function[{x, y, z}, {x*y + z, z^2*x}, Listable];
h[in1, in2, in3]

(* {{a*m + x, a*x^2}, {b*n + y, b*y^2}, {c*o + z, c*z^2}} *)
```